# Transform button into text after condition is true

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui, web3js

I'm using the AppBar component of material-ui library, I added a button, I'd say it's hardcoded in the AppBar, I'm trying to transform this button to just a text in the AppBar, but I got nothing.

How can I transform the button in the AppBar to just text?

App.js:

```
const connectWalletChecker = () => {

    return(
      <div>
        <SearchAppBar id='walletButton' apptitle={apptitle} color='primary' variant='contained' text='Connect Wallet' handle={connectWalletPressed}/>
      </div>
    )
  }

const AlreadyConnected = () => {

    return(
      <div>
        <SearchAppBar id='walletButton' apptitle={apptitle} color='primary' variant='contained' text={walletAddress} handle={null}/>
      </div>
    )
  }

  return(
    <div>
      {walletAddress ? AlreadyConnected() : connectWalletChecker()}
      
    </div>
  )
};
```

AppBar:

```
<Button id={props.id} color={props.color} variant={props.variant} 
href="#contained-buttons" onClick={props.handle}>{props.text}</Button>
```

Full code on [Github](https://github.com/PovedaAqui/bookverse-celo-fe).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `variant="text"` instead of `variant="contained"` for transforming button into text.

your code will be :

```
const connectWalletChecker = () => {

    return(
      <div>
        <SearchAppBar id='walletButton' apptitle={apptitle} color='primary' variant='text' text='Connect Wallet' handle={connectWalletPressed}/>
      </div>
    )
  }

const AlreadyConnected = () => {

    return(
      <div>
        <SearchAppBar id='walletButton' apptitle={apptitle} color='primary' variant='text' text={walletAddress} handle={null}/>
      </div>
    )
  }

  return(
    <div>
      {walletAddress ? AlreadyConnected() : connectWalletChecker()}
      
    </div>
  )
};
```

Comment: It's working! Feel free to add the link to the documentation about it because I haven't found it yet. Thanks!

Comment: Great to hear its working. thanks. https://mui.com/material-ui/react-button/
Check basic button its mention there.